# python: how to know the index when you randomly select an element from a sequence with random.choice(seq)

Tags: python, random, indexing

I know very well how to select a random item from a list with `random.choice(seq)` but how do I know the index of that element?

Comment: Another possibility would be to choose the index randomly and then access the sequence by index.

Answer (score 39):

```
import random
l = ['a','b','c','d','e']
i = random.choice(range(len(l)))
print i, l[i]
```

Comment: Such an elegant answer.

Comment: Valid also with random.choices(range(len(l)), k=n), where n is the number of random draws you want.

Answer (score 16):

You could first choose a random index, then get the list element at that location to have both the index and value.

```
>>> import random
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> index = random.randint(0,len(a)-1)
>>> index
0
>>> a[index]
1
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do it using *randrange* function from *random* module

```
import random
l = ['a','b','c','d','e']
i = random.randrange(len(l))
print i, l[i]
```

Answer (score 3):

The most elegant way to do so is **random.randrange**:

```
index = random.randrange(len(MY_LIST))
value = MY_LIST[index]
```

One can also do this in python3, less elegantly (but still better than `.index`) with **random.choice** on a **range** object:

```
index = random.choice(range(len(MY_LIST)))
value = MY_LIST[index]
```

The only valid solutions are this solution and the `random.randint` solutions.

The ones which use `list.index` not only are slow (`O(N)` per lookup rather than `O(1)`; gets really bad if you do this for each element, you'll have to do `O(N^2)` comparisons) but ALSO you will have skewed/incorrect results if the list elements are not unique.

One would think that this is slow, but it turns out to only be slightly slower than the other correct solution `random.randint`, and may be more readable. I personally consider it more elegant because one doesn't have to do numerical index fiddling and use unnecessary parameters as one has to do with `randint(0,len(...)-1)`, but some may consider this a feature, though one needs to know the `randint` convention of an inclusive range `[start, stop]`.

*Proof of speed for random.choice:* The only reason this works is that the `range` object is OPTIMIZED for indexing. As proof, you can do `random.choice(range(10**12))`; if it iterated through the entire list your machine would be slowed to a crawl.

edit: I had overlooked randrange because the docs seemed to say "don't use this function" (but actually meant "this function is pythonic, use it"). Thanks to martineau for pointing this out.

You could of course abstract this into a function:

```
def randomElement(sequence):
    index = random.randrange(len(sequence))
    return index,sequence[index]

i,value = randomElement(range(10**15))  # try THAT with .index, heh
                                        # (don't, your machine will die)
                                        # use xrange if using python2
# i,value = (268840440712786, 268840440712786)
```

Comment: In exactly what way is this "more elegant" than `randint`?

Comment: @martineau: "and **may** be more readable" - sure, I'll clarify a bit [edited]

Comment: Hmmm, seems like `randrange(len(MY_LIST))` might be even more elegant then (no need for `-1` or separate `range()`) -- don't know about speed though (because I don't have Py3 installed) but the 2.7 docs say it doesn’t actually build a range object.

Comment: @martineau: thank you, that is odd. I had looked at that function before, and the documentation was ambiguous, implying it "is not what you want in Python", so I assumed it was a low-level function (like other things the module exposes). Apparently what they meant was that it was "this is more pythonic than that", or some other strange grammatical construct. It definitely would not build a range object.

Comment: +1 for the `randrange` version. I interpreted the docs to mean it's better than `choice(range(start, stop, step))` *because* it doesn’t actually build a `range` object. In the 3.2 docs there's a note that `randint(a, b)` is just an alias for `randrange(a, b+1)` which also seems to imply a preference for it.

Answer (score 2):

If the values are unique in the sequence, you can always say:  `list.index(value)`

Comment: Unfortunately if you use this on each element in the array, it will be `O(N^2)` and gives a very skewed/incorrect results if any value repeats.

Comment: "if any value repeats...", my answer says "if the values are unique".  i appreciate the comment, but please make it specific to *my* answer, instead of just copying/pasting your comment for someone else's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using **randrage()** as has been suggested is a great way to get the index.  By creating a dictionary created via [comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) you can reduce this code to one line as shown below. Note that since this dictionary only has one element, when you call  **popitem()** you get the combined index and value in a tuple.

```
import random

letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

# dictionary created via comprehension
idx, val = {i: letters[i] for i in [random.randrange(len(letters))]}.popitem()

print("index {} value {}" .format(idx, val))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use sample() method also.
If you want to randomly select n elements from list

```
import random
l, n = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 2
index_list = random.sample(range(len(l)), n)
```

index_list will have **unique** indexes.

I prefer sample() over choices() as sample() does not allow duplicate elements in a sequence.